# Android Exo player with cast extension

Tags: android, casting, exoplayer

I'm implementing Video casting for an android app. Currently, my app already uses Exo player.

We have a tutorial of using media player with chrome cast but there is not any helpful tutorial on how to achieve this task with Exo player

I tried using> https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/cast

There isn't much help I found. Looking for a sample app /code.

Comment: I was using this tutorial: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-exoplayer-starters-guide-6350433f256c
And here a example how to use it: https://github.com/ioannisa/udacity-and-p3-baking-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/anifantakis/bakingapp/fragments/RecipeInfoDetailFragment.java

Comment: @DanielSpiess Thank you. I was looking Exo player with casting to chrome cast. information which you have given is more of implementing exoplayer

Comment: I have written an article about it refer: https://medium.com/atomic-robot/how-to-cast-to-the-big-screen-using-chromecast-in-your-android-app-with-exoplayer2-eab99e8db6ab

Comment: @AkhilaMadari I read your article and I pull the project and run into my device, but the cast button is not visible. youtube cast with my android TV seems working. Is this because I'm not registered my app as a chrome cast sender ?